# MVC 4 accessing model list on click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an mvc app where I pass a list  to a view. In a most click, I want to be able to render the next item in the last but am having trouble figuring out how to do that efficiently. My approach originally was to use an index i but I realized that one the page is rendered, accessing my model last at i will always leaf to the same result since that item in the list is rendered on page load and can't just be accessed dynamically. Any insight to an approach for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The model can't be accessed as it's only used on the server side.

There are a few ways of solving the problem, you can use Knockout.js or similar client side view model components, once the user click on the button just render then next item from the knockout model.

Or use AJAX to retrieve the next value from the back end and then render it to the screen.

Or generate the whole screen and just hide all items from the user and then display them once the user clicks the button